# Can't get input dimensions right for multivariate LSTM

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, lstm

I am trying to train a recurrent neural network for a time series forecasting problem using LSTM, however I am having trouble getting the input dimensions right.

The data is monthly shop sales for around 50 shops and several thousand items. The target is monthly sales of each item/shop combo, with no lag. The training set is the first 4 timesteps. with the last being validation. (original dataset is 31 months)

I think that my input data is correct, (samples,timesteps,features), and I currently have my targets as (samples, timesteps), but am unsure. My thinking is 
Would greatly appreciate anyone having a look at the error message I am getting and giving their advice.

```
data = data.reshape(521398,4,28)
#targets = targets.reshape(521398,4,1)


xt = data[:,:4,:]
xv = data[:,4:,:]
yt = targets[:,:4]
yv = targets[:,4:]

print(data.shape, targets.shape)
```

(521398, 4, 28) (521398, 4)

```
import tensorflow as tf 
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import LSTM,Dense,Dropout
from keras import models
from keras import layers

model = Sequential()

model.add(LSTM(256, activation = 'relu', input_shape = (4,28)))
model.add(Dropout(0.4))
model.add(Dense(4,))

model.compile(loss = 'mse', optimizer = 'adam', accuracy = 'mae')

history = model.fit(xt,yt,batch_size = 4096, epochs = 20,validation_data = (xv, yv))
```

This throws error:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
----> 1 history = model.fit(xt,yt,batch_size = 4096, epochs = 20,validation_data = (xv, yv))

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/training_utils.py in standardize_input_data(data, names, shapes, check_batch_axis, exception_prefix)
    139                             ': expected ' + names[i] + ' to have shape ' +
    140                             str(shape) + ' but got array with shape ' +
--> 141                             str(data_shape))
    142     return data
    143

> ValueError: Error when checking input: expected lstm_1_input to have shape (4, 28) but got array with shape (0, 28)

Comment: I think it would be helpful to check the shape of the `xv` array. The `data` array has shape `(521398, 4, 28)`  but in later you are trying to assign `xv = data[:,4:,:]`, if i'm not mistaken this might result in an empty array for `xv`.

Comment: @ManikTharaka thanks so much, can't believe that was the issue lol